# How to set a datasource on a nested control list on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource

I am trying here to set correctly a Datasource of a nested control list.

Basic idea :

I have an asp:repeater item. Inside there is a DropDownList and a BulletedList plus a Button.

I want to add the selected Item in the DropDownList from the selected row in the Repeater to be added into the selected row's BulletedList.

So far I managed to do that with OnItemDataBound and OnClick wich is quite good. The problem is the event OnClick is fired *after* OnItemDataBdound. To view then the Item I added in the BulletedList's datasource I have to refresh the page.

I tried this :

```
((BulletedList)src.FindControl("sharedPlanDomains")).Items.Clear();
```

and then

```
((BulletedList)src.FindControl("sharedPlanDomains")).Datasource = myobject;
((BulletedList)src.FindControl("sharedPlanDomains")).DataBind();
```

But it seems that it is not working.

```
((BulletedList)src.FindControl("sharedPlanDomains")).DomainsAssociated.ForEach(f => list.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = f.Name }));
```

Doesn't work either.

Any suggestions available ?

[Edit: Clarifications]

Say I have this structure:

- Hosting Plan : i-Perso
  Domains : [The dropdownlist] [Button: Associate]
  Associated Domains :

  - google.com
  - google2.com
- Hosting Plan : i-Mense
  Domains : [The dropdownlist] [Button: Associate]
  Associated Domains :

  - google3.com

so let's take example that I click on the 1st dropdownlist and select the domain google4.com, then google4.com is going to be added in the datasource of the bulletedlist of the row i-Perso.

What I want to do here is to associate domains and plans. I would have done it better if it would be only a relationship of 1 - 1 but it's a relationshop of 1 - Multiple.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question the way it's phrased.  You want to databind the item on a click event, or do you want nested data structures (like a standard nested repeater scenario)?

Comment: I tried here to clarify my goal and what I want to do here, hopes it helps. Ask if there's anything blurry.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the *datasource* of your inner list view to a property of the items bound to your outer *listview*. However, to do that the inner listview as to be in the *item template* of the outer *listview*.

See the code below and note the `DataSource='<%# Eval("Labels_color") %>`' attribute for the inner list view.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView_Orp_Results" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder">
 <LayoutTemplate>
    <div id="outer_result_container">
        <div id="itemPlaceholder" />
    </div>
 </LayoutTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
     <div id="result_photo">...</div>
     <div id="result_category">...</div>
     <div id="result_detector">...</div>
     <div id="inner_result_container" runat="server">
         <asp:ListView ID="ListView_inner_results" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" DataSource='<%# Eval("Labels_color") %>'>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div id="outer_result_container" runat="server" >
                    <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"> </div>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <div id="inner_result_photo">...
                </div>
                <div id="inner_result_category">...
                </div>
                <div id="inner_result_categoryID">...
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
     </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

This way you don't need to bond the nested *listview* from the code behind. Just bind the main *listview*, and all inner *listview* will be automatically bound to the Labels_texture property of the bound objects

About the runat="server" it is a required attribute for asp.net controls. Basically, this attribute means that asp.net will parse the tag and create a corresponding object.

Most of the time you don't need it on *html* elements (div, p, ...) but under some circumstance you might want it to manipulate the corresponding object in your code behind.